# Unbind SLIME's slime-edit-uses (M-_)

Tags: key-bindings, slime, undo-tree-mode

I installed [`undo-tree-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree) into my emacs. It does have a lot of nifty features, one of them being `undo-tree-redo` (bound to `M-_`). It so useful that I put the following code inside my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
;; Always activate undo-tree-mode because of redo (M-_)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'undo-tree-mode)
```

After some time, I started learning LISP and installed [`slime-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SlimeMode). However, now whenever I press `M-_` while in `lisp-mode` the command `slime-edit-uses` is executed instead of `undo-tree-redo`. Even after adding the following (trying to follow the suggestions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324644/emacs-unbind-a-modes-keybinding) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965966/unset-key-binding-in-emacs) questions, and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4tfcc1/overriding_key_binding_in_orgmode/) and [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit#toc3) links) to my `init.el` doesn't bring back `undo-tree-redo` to `M-_`:

```
;; Unbind slime's keybind's hijacking
(defun override-slime ()
  (define-key slime-repl-mode-map
    (read-kbd-macro paredit-backward-delete-key) nil)
  (define-key slime-repl-mode-map (kbd "M-_") nil)
  (define-key slime-mode-indirect-map (kbd "M-_") nil)
  (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "M-_") 'undo-tree-redo))

(eval-after-load "slime-mode"
  '(define-key slime-mode-indirect-map (kbd "M-_") nil))

(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'override-slime)
```

How can I bring `undo-tree-redo` back to `M-_`?

---

**PS:** I don't think any other code of my `init.el` may be influencing or doing something funny with the code above. In any case, [here is my `init.el`](https://pastebin.com/0bjYDGnZ).

**PS2:** `C-h k M-_` returns:

```
M-_ runs the command slime-edit-uses (found in
slime-mode-indirect-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in ‘../elpa/slime-2.20/slime.el’.

It is bound to M-?, M-_.
```

However `M-?` is an inconvenient keybind for me. I'm using Emacs 25.2.2.